# localStorage values are not persist on other pages

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

i am using localStorage on my app and its value is not get persist on other pages. Is it a limitation or i am doing something wrong. Below is my code.

```
  if(!localStorage.getItem("myDataList")){
   localStorage.setItem("myDataList", JSON.stringify(myDataList));
}

if(localStorage.getItem("myDataList")){
   myUserObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myDataList")).myDataList;
}
```

Comment: Multiple syntax errors.

Comment: @Scimonster, i have updated my code with the correct syntax. But still the value get lost when i travese from one page to other page in the same domain. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong syntax, try this

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("myDataList")){
   localStorage.setItem("myDataList", JSON.stringify(myDataList));
}

if(localStorage.getItem("myDataList")){
   myUserObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myDataList")).myDataList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @isvforall. But no luck. still the value not get persisit. I will update my question with your code.

Comment: @user5970552 I've just tried, it's working, your error in somewhere else, need more info